# Adding checkBoxes to UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, uniformgrid

I am trying to dynamically add checkboxes to an uniformgrid in wpf.
But it looks like the grid doesn't allocate them enough space and so they all kinda lay over each other. 
This is how I add them in code behind:

```
foreach (string folder in subfolders)
{
  PathCheckBox chk = new PathCheckBox();
  chk.Content = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
  chk.FullPath = folder;
  chk.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
  chk.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;        

  unfiformGridSubfolders.Children.Add(chk);
}
```

This is how my XAML looks (I placed the uniformgrid in a scrollviewer)

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
  <UniformGrid x:Name="unfiformGridSubfolders" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is how it looks in the program:

[image]

I just want that every checkBox has enough space, so that the content can be fully read.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What if there is one folder taking up the whole width? Do you want everything to take up whole width? UniformGrid, makes each cell uniform, meaning all cells are **identical** size.

Comment: Then how can I do it, that each cell has the size of the checkBox with the biggest content?

Comment: Try a WrapPanel. Or set a style to set the width of all checkboxes, but you'll end up with scrollbars due to overflow and it won't be a very nice solution (see previous comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you **have to** add UI elements dynamically? can't you just predefine your `CheckBox` template and add `CheckBox.Content` instead? If it's possible then define an `ObservableCollection` that contains your `CheckBox.Content`like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SubfolderNames { get; set; }
```

then define an `ItemsControl` and bind it's `ItemsSource` to your collection:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridSubfolders" ItemsSource="{Binding SubfolderNames}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="50" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This way, All Items have the same width as they share a size group, moreover because they are sized `Auto`, they will also size to the largest `CheckBox.Content`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like `WrapPanel`

> Then how can I do it, that each cell has the size of the checkBox with the biggest content?

Using a UniformGrid You would have to manually go through each checkbox, checking its size, and modifying the Uniform Grid.Columns to something like `Math.Floor(Grid.CurrentWidth / CheckBoxMaxWidth)`

Answer (score 0):

When the `Rows` and the `Columns` property of a `UniformGrid` are both set to zero the `UniformGrid` tries to layout the elements in a square without regarding the size of the elements. I'd write a panel that layouts your elements as you want it like the following one. Just use `MyPanel` instead of `UniformGrid` in your XAML.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        int columns;
        int rows;

        protected override Size MeasureOverride (Size constraint)
        {
            Size childConstraint = constraint;
            double maxChildDesiredWidth = 0.0;
            double maxChildDesiredHeight = 0.0;

            if (InternalChildren.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];

                    // Measure the child.
                    child.Measure (childConstraint);
                    Size childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;

                    if (maxChildDesiredWidth < childDesiredSize.Width)
                    {
                        maxChildDesiredWidth = childDesiredSize.Width;
                    }

                    if (maxChildDesiredHeight < childDesiredSize.Height)
                    {
                        maxChildDesiredHeight = childDesiredSize.Height;
                    }
                }

                columns = (int)(constraint.Width / maxChildDesiredWidth);
                rows = (int)(InternalChildren.Count / columns + 0.5);
            }
            else
            {
                columns = 0;
                rows = 0;
            }

            return new Size ((maxChildDesiredWidth * columns), (maxChildDesiredHeight * rows));
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride (Size arrangeSize)
        {
            Rect childBounds = new Rect (0, 0, arrangeSize.Width / columns, arrangeSize.Height / rows);
            double xStep = childBounds.Width;
            double xBound = arrangeSize.Width - 1.0;

            childBounds.X += 0;

            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Arrange (childBounds);

                if (child.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    childBounds.X += xStep;
                    if (childBounds.X >= xBound)
                    {
                        childBounds.Y += childBounds.Height;
                        childBounds.X = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            return arrangeSize;
        }
    }
}
```